# jQuery and Local Storage: Selector with Multiple States

Tags: jquery, css, fonts, local-storage, prop

I am currently working on a drop-down for changing the fonts on a site.  Presently, there are a few different fonts available from the drop-down.  The code that is called when one of the drop-down sections is clicked is as follows:

```
jQuery(function($) {
if ( localStorage.getItem('font-01') ) {
    $('#font-css-01').prop('disabled', localStorage.getItem('font-01') == 'true');
}

$('#font-selector-01').on('click', function() {
    $('#font-css-01').prop('disabled', function(_, prop) {
        localStorage.setItem('font-01', !prop);
        return !prop;
    });
});
});
```

Now, this script repeats for each font option (with only the ending numbers changed, obviously).  However, I need the script to disable any previous font choices when enabling the new font choice; presently, unexpected behaviour can arise when a user selects a non-default font and then selects *another* non-default font (e.g., selects font-01, then selects font-02).  In essence, I'm not sure how to go about expanding this script so it resets previous choices before applying new choices.

The `.prop()` function is targeting the stylesheet ids for the various fonts, and the drop-down's subitems are labelled consecutively `#font-selector-01` through `$font-selector-n`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For `link` tags use `data-fid` instead of `id`:

```
<link data-fid='01' href='...' rel='...' disabled>
<link data-fid='02' href='...' rel='...' disabled>
```

As you can see, they should be disabled by default.
Add class `font-selector-c` and attribute `data-fid='xx'` to each `li`.
Then the code:

```
$('.font-selector-c').on('click', function() {
    var fid = $(this).data('fid')
    $('link[data-fid]').prop('disabled', true) // disable all the stylesheets
    $('link[data-fid="' + fid + '"]')
        .prop('disabled', false) // enable one needed
    localStorage.setItem('font', fid) // save the id of the selected
});
$('#font-selector-reset').on('click', function() {
    $('link[data-id]').prop('disabled', true) // disable all the stylesheets
    localStorage.setItem('font', null) // remove saved id
});

// On start: recalling user's choice
var c_fid = localStorage.getItem('font')
if (c_fid)
    $('link[data-fid="' + c_fid + '"]').prop('disabled', false)
```

Comment: That doesn't seem to have quite worked.  Here's a link to the HTML with which I'm currently working (including links for all of the scripts): http://zyniker13.com/html-pages/tutorial-create-a-drop-down-to-select-the-font-for-your-site.html.  As you can likely tell, I'm trying to make the drop-down at the top of the page act as a font selector (with a reset-to-default button, too).

Comment: @Zyniker What exactly is supposed to happen? What does `prop disabled` do in your opinion?

Comment: Here's how I intend for the drop-down to function:  If a user selects one of the fonts on the drop-down, I want the jQuery attached to it to disabled any previous font choices (i.e., reset to the default) and simultaneously activate the new font choice; from the code perspective, this would consist of ensuring that all the add-on stylesheets for the various font choices are disabled, except the last one the user chose.  And the reset button, somewhat obviously, would simply disable all of the add-on stylesheets for the font choices (i.e., reset the site to the default font/CSS).

Comment: After you inserted my code, it works like that: when user clicks an option, for example `font-selector-03`, value of `font-01` in local storage is set to `03`. (Actually I made a mistake in the code, it should have been `setItem('font', fid)`. So, now font-03 is selected. What is the problem? Attach one more event on the default button: just `localStorage.setItem('font', null)`.

Comment: Please see the example here: http://zyniker13.com/html-pages/tutorial-create-a-drop-down-to-select-the-font-for-your-site.html.  As you can see, the font drop-down is not behaving as expected.  I'm not sure where the code is going awry.

Comment: That's the problem, you do not mention how it is supposed to behave. Now it just puts a value in the local storage. What else should it do?

Comment: I'm not actually attached to the idea of using `.prop()`, I simply started from the code I used in another project, and I am attempting to modify it to fit this project.  What I need the code to do (regardless of how it accomplishes it) is activate the relevant stylesheet (i.e., the one for the font the user selects) and ensure that all other font-specific stylesheets are deactivated (so there are no conflicts or unexpected behaviour).  As for the reset button, it simply need to make sure that all font-specific stylesheets are disabled (so that the site's style reflects the default font).

Comment: @Zyniker I changed the code in my answer. Now it should disable link tags. I don't really understand why localStorage is needed, so explain please.

Comment: I was using localStorage in the other project (and I believe I'll need it in this one) so that the user's choices *persist* across a given site and across visits.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, Serge.  As you can see on the example page: http://zyniker13.com/html-pages/tutorial-create-a-drop-down-to-select-the-font-for-your-site.html, everything but the reset is now working.  Not sure if I missed something, or if the code needs a tweak.

Comment: Looks like "id" on the third-to-last line needed to be changed to "fid".  Everything appears to be working now.  Once again, thank you very much for your help.

Comment: You are welcome. As you can see, I added a couple of lines to the end to restore value saved in storage.

Comment: Hey Serge, thought I'd post here and see if you'd mind taking a look at this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20292203/rework-jquery-scripts-to-utilize-wildcard-targeting-of-classes-ids.  The code being used is relatively similar to what was involved here and I thought you might know how to fix the code in the other thread.